# How can I create a custom page with a different template?

Tags: theming, 7

I want to have a page (e.g. the one at http://example.com/mypage) shown as a blank page. How can I use a different template for that specific page, to show it as a blank page?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a different template for a page by suggesting a new template file that will be used.

This can be done in a theme, by writing its `template_preprocess_page()`, or in a module by implementing `hook_preprocess_page()`.

```
function template_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (arg(0) == "node" && arg(1) == "1") {
    array_unshift($variables['theme_hook_suggestions'], "page--custom-template");
  }
}
```

This code is for Drupal 7; for Drupal 6 you need to replace `$variables['theme_hook_suggestions']` with `$variables['template_files']`. In the case you are using it in a module, `template_preprocess_page()` needs to be renamed `mymodule_preprocess_page()`, where "mymodule" is the short name of your module.
Instead of using `arg()` you can also use `request_uri()`, but the output returned from this function is similar to "/dr72/devel/php?render=overlay&render=overlay" when Drupal is installed in a subdirectory of the web server's root directory. `request_uri()` doesn't change an alias into the canonical path; supposing that example.com/node-1-title is an alias for example.com/node/1, in my test site, the function will return "/dr72/node-1-title" while `arg(0)` and `arg(1)` would return, respectively, "node" and "1" (the first two elements of the path).

Comment: When i use theme_hook_suggestions , Drupal return a page with content of "page--custom-template.tpl.php" in to the default template. This page content show in the body. i want a blank page.

Comment: Just use an empty template file; in that way, Drupal will return a page that doesn't even contain any Drupal block.

Comment: how can i get url to this page?

Comment: Use `arg()`, or `request_uri()`, taking in consideration what I reported in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement this in code, within a custom theme or module, you need to look into [template suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089656).

If you want a ui-based solution, there are a few modules that assist in having custom themes for specific themes/sections of your site. See [themekey module](http://drupal.org/project/themekey),  [custom page module](http://drupal.org/project/custompage) and [page theme module](http://drupal.org/project/page_theme) for a few modules that do this.

Personally, I would opt for a template suggesion in a custom module.

Comment: I want a code but when i use "template suggestion" , the page has default template at section "<head>". I need a blank page with different template.
Happy new year man.

Comment: This is easy to do in a custom theme. See this link for various examples: http://drupal.org/node/1041768.

Comment: oh tnx alot my friend. i take it.

Answer (score 0):

```
function yourTheme_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
    if($node->type == "mypage") {
      $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'html__mypage';
    }
  }
}
```

then we can access to this page from : http://yoursite.com/?q=mypage or in clear url mode : http://yoursite.com/mypage/